# Using jqgrid to perform crud over users table

Tags: model-view-controller, jqgrid, passwords

I am adding an admin page to my mvc.net site that will allow crud operations over a users table so that an admin can change user names, email addresses and passwords.

I'd like to user jqgrid to do this but am not sure how to get the edit pop up to include password and password confirmation controls if they are not columns in the view model.

Has anyone got any advice?